# After upgrading to ASP.NET Core 3.0, I get "Could not create stdoutLogFile ErrorCode = -2147024893."

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, web-config, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm upgrading an existing ASP.NET Core 2.2 application to `3.0`.

When I publish and host my APIs inside local IIS, I get the **HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure** page. The point is, I don't see the logs being written to the `stdoutLogFile` location.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\bin\MyApplication.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\bin\Logs\" hostingModel="inprocess" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I've changed the output folder from `\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\` to `\bin\` via these configurations:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputPath>.\bin</OutputPath>
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
    <AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>false</AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I also have a folder called `Logs` in my `\bin\` folder.

But when I call my API, I get this error in *Error Viewer*:

> Warning: Could not create stdoutLogFile
>   C:\PathToMyProjectFile\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2_19212_2019102292022.log,
>   ErrorCode = -2147024893.

The point is, I'm not using 2.2 anymore. How should I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

you have to modify the generated web.config by removing the "V2" in modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2", in order to have: modules="AspNetCoreModule".
Hope this helps